# How to get web-2-lead description text to activity?

Tags: leads, lead-conversion, activities, web2lead

Salesforce is very good and consistent in logging all kind of communication with users from lead to paying customer. It is great to see all activities, be they mails, call logs or meeting notes.

There is one exception though: Web-2-Lead

When someone registers on our website, web to lead generates a new lead in Salesforce. However, the message the leads sends, only get stored in a description field. When you convert the lead, this message gets saved in a field that is below the contact. That is very inconsistent.

In my opinion, this first message is already an activity. As such, it should be linked with an opportunity or at least account or contact.

Is there a way to automatically transform the description field to an activity under the contact (or later, for the first opportunity that is linked to it)?

Here are some screenshots to make the case clear:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need a trigger to handle this, since Workflow cannot create an Activity.

Here's a rough outline of the steps for an After Insert trigger:

1. Lead is created
2. Check if Lead Source is Web2Lead. If not, exit.
3. Create new Activity
4. Assign Activity to the new Lead
5. Copy Lead.Description into Activity
6. Insert Activity

Later on, this Activity would transfer over to the Account/Contact when the Lead is converted.